# System.ArgumentException: 'Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am working on a piece of code which will display different options for the user within a combobox. The options come from a mysql database and its having trouble fetching it.

```
        Try
            dbConnection()
            sql = “SELECT Name From parts WHERE (Type = 'CPU');”
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim data As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dta As New DataTable
            data.Fill(dta)
            NameComboBox1.DataSource = data
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
```

And this is the dbConnection module

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module ConnectionModule

    Public conn As MySqlConnection
    Public cmd As MySqlCommand
    Public dr As MySqlDataAdapter
    Public dt As DataTable
    Public sql As String
    Public result As Integer

    Public Sub dbConnection()
        Try
            conn = New MySqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = “server=localhost; userid=root; password=; database=partstest1; CharSet=utf8;”
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

This is the first time using mysql with vb so i am really confused, any tips with the way i code would be great.
This is also my first time posting on stack so any tips on how to structure my question would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you set the combobox's DataSource to the datatable, dta?

Comment: It no longer shows the error however hasn't fixed it as the drop downbox options are all named "System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: Have you set the combobox's DisplayMember to the column you want to display and the combobox's ValueMember to the column you want the combobox to return when you select an item?

Comment: Can I just say that `data` and `dta` are terrible names in this context. For one thing, they are easily confused. For another, neither describes the thing it refers to. A data adapter contains no actual data, so why call it `data`? Call it `adapter` or `dataAdapter` or `partsDataAdapter` or something that appropriately describes what it actually is. Similarly, `dta` should be `table` or `dataTable` or `partsTable` or some such. When you use VS with advanced Intellisense, naming everything with as few characters as possible is false economy and counter productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you need to set the `DisplayMember` of the `ComboBox` to the name of the column you want displayed. In your case, that appears to be "Name".

```vb
With NameComboBox1
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .DataSource = dta
End With
```

If you were retrieving the primary key column as well then you'd assign its name to the `ValueMember` property and then, when you selected a `Name` value from the list, you could get the corresponding PK value from the `SelectedValue`. As it is, you can get the selected `Name` value from the `Text` property.

Note that you should always set the `DataSource` last, as I have done above. It is possible to set it first but that means that the bindings have to change when you set the `DisplayMember` and/or `ValueMember`. If you set the `DataSource` last then the bindings are setup once only.

The reason that you see "System.Data.DataRowView" when you don't set the `DisplayMember` is that, in order to get text to display for an item, the default is to call its `ToString` method. When you bind a `DataTable`, which is an `IListSource`, its `GetList` method is called to get an `IList`, which is its `DefaultView`, which is type `DataView`, which contains `DataRowView` objects. The default behaviour for the `ToString` method is to simply return the full type name, so that's what you see.

Comment: This solved it thanks, and thank you for explaining it too it made a lot of sense